# How to get split string with special characters in android?

Tags: android

I have a string named namely "-10.00","-100.00","-1000.00". I want to get value like "10","100","1000" from that string. I have tried to get substring but did not able to get.

code i have tried

```
String amount = "-10.00";
String trimwalletBalance = amount.substring(0, amount.indexOf('.'));
```

From above i only get "-10".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String trimwalletBalance = amount.substring(1, amoun.indexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple.

Do it like `String trimwalletBalance = amount.substring(1, amount.indexOf('.'));`

Instead of position 0, You should get substring from position 1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String amount = "-10.00";
int value = (int) Double.parseDouble(amount);
if(value < 0) value *= -1;
//value will be 10
```

OR

```
String text = amount.substring(1, amount.indexOf('.'));
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt can't parse a floating value.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into integer and then name it positive:

```
String amount = "-10.00";
int amountInt = (int) Double.parseDouble(amount);
if(amountInt<0)amountInt*=-1;
```